# Issue with struct in header

Tags: c, header, struct

Hi everyone I'm running into problems with placing a c struct in a header file so it can be shared. I haven't found a solution yet that actually compiles without error so I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Header File awget.h

```
#ifdef awget_H
#define awget_H

typdef struct List{
char IPs;
}List;

#endif
```

Source File awget.c

```
#include "awget.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 List receiveHere;
 struct List sendHere;

 return 0;
}
```

The first declaration in the source file returns, "error: unknown type name ‘List’".
The second declaration returns, "error: storage size of ‘sendHere’ isn’t known".

From what I've been able to gather the first should be a legal declaration, but I'm clearly doing it wrong. I've tried extern and typedefs and read every c struct in header article I could find to try to properly understand how to put a struct in a header to no avail, let alone something that compiled properly.

Can someone either point me in the direction of a proper resource or shed some light on what I have setup incorrectly? Thank you for your time.

Comment: That misspelled `typedef` isn't a transposition typo, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) It is `#ifndef`, as in *'if not defined'* you should use.

Change

> #ifdef awget_H

with

> #ifndef awget_H

2) It is `typedef` not `typdef`.

3) If it is not C++, it must be `List sendHere` not `struct List sendHere`.

Comment: *facepalm* Between trying to change so many things around I messed up with spelling errors. Thank you.